# What muscles are targeted when doing inclined dips and push ups

Tags: weight-gain, exercise-technique, push-ups, dips

I basically do 20-25 dips which is slightly inclined towards the wall and then some push ups of 20-25 for starting. The height is 5Ft 11 and weight 69.1kgs Male for which  i am underweight.

My question is what kind of muscle is being targeted when doing the inclined dip and the push ups.My goal is to remove fatigue and weight gain.
Is it the appropriate kind of exercise that i do or i need to bring in some changes.Willing to give commitment for it.Images or links would be helpful for correct technique

Time and space are my constraints please suggest accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to remove fatigue? Do you want to become more endurant?
Doing dips and push ups will not influence your weight noticably; you will need lost of changes to your program if weight loss is the goal.

Comment: @DarkoSarovic Yes enduring as well as weight gain. What changes are you suggesting me in my exercise (for both)

Comment: For endurance do 20+ reps. For lean weight gain do 8-12 reps. Add more exercises, compound ones, such as squats, deadlifts and rows, for increased weight gain.

Comment: @DarkoSarovic how can I add more excersies with time and space constrain.I only have time to do in the home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of muscles are being trained when doing forward tilted dips.

[image]

- Triceps

  - Long head
  - Lateral head
  - Medial head
- Front Deltoid
- Pectoral major (generally the lower pectoral area )

Push ups are excellent for core conditioning and also target the same general muscles as the dip but in a slightly different variation.

[image]

The push up also focus more on:

- Pectoral major
- Pectoral clavicle
- Triceps
- Anconeus

Comment: Is there any difference for tilted dips against the wall and the normal dips (lying on the stomach)

Comment: dips against the wall ?  Are you referring to wall push-ups ?  See images in my answer for what a dip is.

Comment: A push-up against the wall will target a pectoral muscle more in the upper part and more in the middle when on the floor.

Comment: Don't forget the serratus! These are the best two movements for its development!

Comment: @user10019 and what does the serratus mean

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serratus_anterior_muscle